# Racial advantages/disadvantages for a rules light system

Tags: character-creation, races, warrior-rogue-and-mage

I started a lunch break rpg with some of my coworkers last week, using Michael Wolf's Warrior, Rogue and Mage system. The first session was fun, with character creation and some explanation of what an RPG is. But, some players wanted to play races (Dark Elf, Undead) that are not described on the PDF, and I want to give these races some sort of advantage and disadvantage, to balance them out with the rest. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! This is a question suited to [a discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321), but as you can see in our [tour] we are different from such forums and laser-focused on solving specific problems rather than giving suggestions. If you have a specific roadblock preventing your own creativity with this, asking about that specifically may be a problem we could solve, but for just suggestions I will recommend one of [these forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) instead.